# TFS - Build and Release, configuration file provider

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there any similar plugin like this

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

in **TFS Build & Release**

I want to provide configuration.json file which is not included in git source.

Comment: no, I'm not on XAML build, I follow the suggestion from TFS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=vsts&tabs=apple-install-during-build

Comment: thank you for your help and response @PatrickLu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such extension in TFS/VSTS Build & Release.

According to your tag *tfs2013*, seems you are working with **XAML** build.

Just like you need a workspace on your dev machine to develop your app, you must specify the workspace that the build agent uses to build and test your app. Then we get/pull source files from TFS server side.  It's not able to achieve below similar features in TFS UI:

> Adds the ability to provide configuration files (i.e., settings.xml
>   for maven, XML, groovy, custom files, etc.) loaded through the Jenkins
>   UI which will be copied to the job's workspace.

As a workaround, you could  try to put configuration.json files in a ftp server instead of git source and then use a PowerShell solution to down the files in build agent workspace. If create a PowerShell to  over FTP you can have it called by the build template(customize workflow).